# Error of the emulator: "Unable to access 'C:\Users\...\.emulator_console_auth_token': emulator console will not work", with username in Cyrillic

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

My username is written in Cyrillic which is why when I run the android studio emulator I get an error:

> Emulator: ERROR: Unable to access
>   'C:\Users\РђР»РµРєСЃР°РЅРґСЂ.emulator_console_auth_token': emulator
>   console will not work

Is there any way to migrate the path to this file?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem with this video [How to Rename the User’s Folder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_rTOA4gXJI) by changing Windows username to **non Cyrillic**. Same video in Russian language [Как переименовать папку пользователя](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BFVpnR2XNS4)
In my opinion, it is better to create a new user with **Latin** letters and programming there, because after renaming there may be problems with the programs. If problems appears, then search and rename the paths through regedit (ctrl + f and type "C:\users\HERE YOUR USERNAME") as shown in the video.
**Do at your own risk!**

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by making a folder in my user directory with the folder name that the error printed (in your case РђР»РµРєСЃР°РЅРґСЂ), and then making an empty .emulator_console_auth_token file in that directory.

This will disable authentication: (https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-console).

> To disable authentication, delete the token from the .emulator_console_auth_token file or create an empty file if it doesn't exist.

But I doubt that will be a problem

Comment: I was very surprised to see that this solution actually worked for me!