# Unable to access .emulator_console_auth_token

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

I recently installed Android Studio and I just wanted to run a basic app on emulator. Firstly, I have encountered several issues because Windows user name contains non-ASCI character. After I set `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`, `ANDROID_AVD_HOME` and `ANDROID_EMULATOR_HOME` environment variables, I manage to run the emulator. But I couldn't compile and run the android application on it as it times out. When I start the emulator it gives the following error:

```
Emulator: ERROR: Unable to access 'C:\Users\.....\.emulator_console_auth_token': emulator console will not work
```

I believe non-ASCII issue causes this error but I have nothing else to do. I cannot change my username.

So far, I have tried to make a link folder and edit all my environment variables using that link.

Can anyone help me about this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error of the emulator: "Unable to access 'C:\Users\...\.emulator\_console\_auth\_token': emulator console will not work", with username in Cyrillic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59336424/error-of-the-emulator-unable-to-access-c-users-emulator-console-auth-to)

Comment: I've seen this answer. As i mentioned on my question, I cannot change the user name.

Comment: What do you mean by "tried to make a link folder"?

Comment: I have used `mklink` command to create a `junction` of that problem folder. I'm not a knowledgable windows admin and I don't know anything about that but essentially I looked for a symlink equivalent in windows.